# calculate the prices for Holiday depends on adults and children

Tags: java

I have asked to build booking holiday system and I have faced a problem with calculating the prices. I do not know how to find the price per room per either adult or child. The system requirements are as the following:

The system allows the user to enter the number of adults and/or children going on the holiday with children charged at half price. the cost per night per adult is 50. what is the equation to find the prices?
For example, if two adults with two children books two rooms for two nights?

Comment: So... How far have you got then?

Comment: Seriously? 2 adults: $50 each. 2 kids: $25 each. That's $150 per night. Two nights: $300.

Comment: please supply code and a more constructive question so someone can help you, but this is like 'do my job please'

Comment: This question us off topic as it appears to be about how to do basic arithmetic.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So the user enters the number of adults and children into the system. Use variables A and C to represent the two respectively. If it is $50 per adult and $25 per child, you end up with the equation total cost = (50A + 25C)*number of nights.

So if two adults and two children book for two nights you get total cost = (50*2+25*2)*2 nights = $300.